# Access is denied HRESULT: 0x80070005

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried debugging one of my projects and while opening a `DataTable` i ended up with the error below.

[image: Error Image]
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have not rights on the `Database` which the `DataTable` refers to. The designer of your `TableAdapters` in Visual Studio, tries to update them self on opening.

So, simply check if your `ConnectionString` is still accurate.